# Add SSRS Report Page List to Enterprise Portal AX 2012

Tags: enterprise-portal, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I want to add SSRS report to Enterprise Portal AX 2012 R2. I've created new web menu item and define web menus based on the new web menu item. In EP the link have been created, but when I clicked the link it showing error "page not found 404".

Can anyone give me any reference or step by step how to add SSRS report to EP?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because of report not properly deployed. Follow the link below to post more queries about your requirement.

http://ax2012enterpriseportal.blogspot.in/2013/06/calling-ssrs-reports-from-ax2012-ep.html